# Equation $x^3+ax^2+bx+26=0$. Find the sum of the absolute values of the possible values of a.

Tags: functions

I tried it by putting the sum and product formula into work for this equation...
All roots are integer.

Comment: @user139024 Do you mean "the possible values of $a$ which makes it so that we can choose a $b$ such that the equation has only integer solutions"? Because as it stands you can choose _any_ value for $a$. There are no restrictions.

Comment: It is what it says. The sum of absolute value...

Comment: Yes, the sum of the absolute value of the _possible_ values of $a$. I'm wondering what makes the difference between possible and impossible values.

Comment: Please update it so it's clear what you are asking.

Comment: What should I add adjustment to?

Comment: For instance, is $1,498,932$ a possible value for $a$? Is $-\sqrt[3]{\ln(\pi)}$ possible? There should be some _restriction_ on either $a$ or more likely the polynomial itself (like, for instance, all solutions are integers, or all solutions are between $0$ and $1$ or something), otherwise you're practically asking for the sum of all positive real numbers.

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot to put the limits. All roots are integers, or the roots could be any real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem only makes sense if x has to be an integer.

Suppose the roots are $p,q,r$, then we can write the equation as:
$$(x−p)(x−q)(x−r)=x^3−(p+q+r)x^2+(pq+pr+qr)x−pqr = 0$$
Now match the coefficients (also known as Vieta's formulas).

It follows that:
$$pqr = -26 = -2\cdot 13 \qquad (1)$$
$$|a| = |p+q+r|$$
Enumerate all sets of possible roots (p, q, r) that satisfy the equation (1).

Afterwards, sum all possibilities of $|a|$.

Comment: Yes it is a integer

Comment: Sorry,I have to let you make the guess

Comment: How you find the product of the roots

Comment: $(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)=x^3-(p+q+r)x^2+(pq+pr+qr)x-pqr$. Now match the coefficients (also known as Vieta's formulas).

Comment: You should add that to the answer.

Comment: Good point. Done.